# Know when dom updates - Angular 2/4

Tags: javascript, html, angular, dom-events

So I'm toggling a certain dom element by ngIf and right after setting it true, I'm also targetting that element by Viewchild - ElementRef. 
The problem is, after toggling, it takes a certain amount of time for the element to be updated in the dom and if I call in a variable holding the element, it will return as null, although after a timeout it will return the element as it got sufficient time so that the dom is updated.

Here is a sample code to understand better:

Html

```
<div #someElement *ngIf="showElement">
some content
</div>
```

Component.ts

```
@ViewChild('someElement') someElement:ElementRef;

toggle() {

this.showElement = true
console.log(this.someElement) //consoles undefined

}
```

Component.ts

```
@ViewChild('someElement') someElement:ElementRef;

toggle() {

this.showElement = true

setTimeout(function() {
    console.log(this.someElement) //Consoles the element
   }, 300) 

}
```

Is there a way this can be done without a timeout in a proper way, like an event to check for dom update or something?

Comment: theres `AfterContentChecked` and `AfterViewChecked`

Comment: learn about `lifecycles` and you will get it ;) https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks